# AEM Skip: Deploy to dispatcher Reason: no dispatcher configuration packages

Tags: aem, dispatcher

Our project is running in the Adobe Cloud Manager, since the first implementation of the project all pipelines have run well but in the log, I can see the following error:

> Skip: Deploy to dispatcher:dispatcher1uswest1 in xxx-prod [id:xxx]. Reason: no dispatcher configuration packages

I reviewed the project and could see the dispatcher module was missing in the main pom, then I added it, now when I run a new pipeline in the Adobe Cloud Manager I got the following error:

> Deploy to instanceId=dispatcher2uswest1 failed with errorCode=10011001 message=Failed to start Apache due to syntax error in deployed configurations, AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/enabled_vhosts/aem_author.vhost:
> Invalid command '../available_vhosts/aem_author.vhost', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

In the mentioned file all look good, so can someone help me to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the guys from Adobe should help you. You are paying them a lot. They can have a better look into the deployment, and hopefully know all the magic they built-in there. Actually we had many times problems with Adobe Cloud and failing deployments, where we didn't changed anything - nor we had any special configuration.

But maybe you could share the first 2 lines of you aem_author.vhost file?

Comment: I have seen this problem before - it's due to how you deal with symbolic links in your git repository. If you're using Windows, that may be a little trouble for you. In this case, your file is not a link but it tries to behave like one (it has the reference to which is supposed to point).

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderBerndt I'll check with those guys. Dawid Pura looks like that's the error, some links are broken, thank you.